# Database schema confusing (Index and Constraints)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I have a *little* confusion about the designing of the schema, but before i start, let me show you the schema first,

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    -- some columns here..
    CONSTRAINT tb_idF INDEX (FirstName),
    CONSTRAINT tb_idL INDEX (LastName)
    -- or 
    -- CONSTRAINT tb_idL INDEX (FirstName, LastName)
    -- other constraints ...
);

CREATE TABLE JobDescription
(
    JobDescriptionID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    JobDescriptionName VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
    -- some columns here..
    -- constraints ...
);
```

and the confusion is here, the *mapping* table for tables: `Person` and `JobDescription`.  Currently, I have this design,

```
CREATE TABLE Person_JobDescription
(
    RECID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   -- for some special reasons
                                            -- I need to map to other table
    PersonID INT,
    JobDescriptionID INT,
    StartYear INT,                          -- year JobDescription was Appointed
    EndYear INT,
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) 
        REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (JobDescriptionID) 
        REFERENCES JobDescription(JobDescriptionID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (PersonID, JobDescriptionID)
);
```

but i have this other idea which structure of the mapping table will be like this

```
CREATE TABLE Person_JobDescription
(
    PersonID INT,           -- map these two columns on the other table
    JobDescriptionID INT,   -- ^^
    StartYear INT,          -- year JobDescription was Appointed
    EndYear INT,
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) 
        REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (JobDescriptionID) 
        REFERENCES JobDescription(JobDescriptionID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, JobDescriptionID)
);
```

when I created and tested the query against the tables above, both of them returns the same results and the performance is also the same as I am testing on a small database (*having 50k records*). I wonder if how the two queries behave on large database.

**QUESTIONS**

- Which of the two schemas of the mapping table (`Person_JobDescription`) will you prefer on large database?

As instructed, I am not allowed to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `FirstName` and `LastName`. But i have supplied an index on the two columns.

- What type of index will I use on table `Person`? An index for each column or a compound index for `FirstName` and `LastName`?
- When will I use single index `INDEX (Col1)` and `INDEX (Col2)` over `INDEX (Col1, Col2)`?

Thank you for taking time to read on this question.

Best Regards,

Derek Floss

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd prefer the second approach. By using surrogate ID numbers when they're not logically necessary for identification, you introduce more mandatory joins. This requires you to "chase ID numbers all over the database", which is the SQL equivalent to "chasing pointers all over the database". Chasing pointers was characteristic of IMS, one of the database architectures the relational model intended to replace. (IMS uses a hierarchical architecture.) There's no point reinventing it today. (Although a *lot* of people do just that.)

If you have, for example, five levels of surrogate ID numbers, and you want a person's name, you have to do four joins to get it. Using the second approach, you just need one join. If you don't want to write multi-column joins, use CREATE VIEW and do it just once.

**Performance is simple to test**. Just generate a few million random-ish rows using your favorite scripting language, and load them into a test server. You'll not only find where your performance problems are hiding, you'll find all the errors in your CREATE TABLE code. (Your code won't work as-is.) Learn about [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) if you don't already know about it.

As for **indexing**, you can test that on the random-ish rows you generate and load. A multi-column index on (first_name, last_name) will work best if users always supply a first name. But a lot of users won't do that, preferring to search by last name instead. A multi-column index on (first_name, last_name) isn't effective for users who prefer to search by last name. You can test that.

For that reason alone, indexing of first names and last names is *usually* more effective if there are two separate indexes, one for the first name, and one for the last name.

---

**What does *chasing id numbers* mean?**

The unspoken design pattern underlying this question is "Every row must have an id number, and all foreign keys must reference the id number." In a SQL database, it's actually an anti-pattern. As a rule of thumb, any pattern that lets you design tables without thinking about keys should be presumed guilty until proven innocent--it should be presumed to be an anti-pattern until proven not to be.

```
create table A (
 a_id integer primary key,
 a_1 varchar(15) not null unique,
 a_2 varchar(15) not null
);

create table B (
  b_id integer primary key
  a_id integer not null references A (a_id),
  b_1  varchar(10) not null,
  unique (a_id, b_1),
);

create table C (
  c_id integer primary key,
  b_id integer not null references B (b_id),
  c_1 char(3) not null,
  c_2 varchar(20) not null,
  unique (b_id, c_1)
);

create table D (
  d_id integer primary key,
  c_id integer not null references C (c_id),
  d_1 integer not null,
  d_2 varchar(15),
  unique (c_id, d_1)
);
```

If you need a report on table "D", and the report needs

- columns D.d_1 and D.d_2, and
- columns A.a_1 and A.a_2,

you need 3 joins to get to it. (Try it.) You're chasing ID numbers. (Like chasing pointers in IMS.) The following structure is different.

```
create table A (
 a_1 varchar(15) primary key,
 a_2 varchar(15) not null
);

create table B (
  a_1 varchar(15) not null references A (a_1),
  b_1  varchar(10) not null,
  primary key (a_1, b_1),
);

create table C (
  a_1 varchar(15) not null,
  b_1 varchar(10) not null,
  c_1 char(3) not null,
  c_2 varchar(20) not null,
  primary key (a_1, b_1, c_1),
  foreign key (a_1, b_1) references B (a_1, b_1)
);

create table D (
  a_1 varchar(15) not null,
  b_1 varchar(10) not null,
  c_1 char(3) not null,
  d_1 integer not null,
  d_2 varchar(15),
  primary key (a_1, b_1, c_1, d_1),
  foreign key (a_1, b_1, c_1) references C (a_1, b_1, c_1)
);
```

With this structure, the same report needs a single join.

```
select D.d_1, D.d_2, A.a_1, A.a_2
from D
inner join A on D.a_1 = A.a_1;
```

Comment: there should always be a `last_name` for every `first_name`. so you mean to say that an index on each column: `first_name` and `last_name`is the same as compound index for the two columns?

Comment: No, they're not the same. If you have one index on last name and one index on first name, the dbms can use whichever it thinks will be faster. Users will get quick response whether they search by first name or by last name. But a single, compound index on {last_name, first_name} usually *won't* be used at all if the user searches by first name.

Comment: Where do you get the extra joins from? An extra key/index yes, but then you are only joining on one value, not multiple ones. The real benefit of surrogate keys though is longevity and resilience, the business types don't have to do much to make complete mess of a design without them, and if it was worth doing in the first place it will last and change.

Comment: Can't disagree with that, as long as nothing changes in terms of the rules around a1 to d1. I tend to go for resilience to change as my first choice optimisation, now if it was mainly for a reporting database, no argument at all.

Answer (score 3):

The first approach would be my preference

If you needed a table dependent on PersonJobDescription, say AgentContact, you can easily link to the surrogate Rec_ID, without it, you have to start jumping through hoops

The other reason would be what if it became a requirement to hold a Person/JobDescription for each year?
Before you know where you are at you'll be having a four vakue compound key that still doesn't do the job.
The rule Compound Primary Keys, should be a last resort will make your designs more flexible and resilient.

Comment: i wanted to accept this answer too, but SO won't. thank you so much! i've given you my upvote.